# How can i write subquery to finish?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables:
1. "authorCollection" contains key and author
2. "book" contains key and year.

Every book has a unique key and a book may have multi-authors.
For example:

```
book:
key  year
1    1999
2    2000
3    2001

authorCollection
key  author
1    Tom
2    Tim
2    Tony
2    Mary
3    Tim
3    Tony
3    Alex
```

I hope to get the average number of different collaborators of authors after year 2000(inclusive).

After year 2000(inclusive),
For Tim, his collab are Tony and Mary and Alex. it is 3 collabs.

For Mary her collab are Tim and Tony. it is 2 collabs.

For Tony, his collab are Tim , Mary and Alex. it is 3 collabs.

For Alex, his collab are Tim and Tony. it is 2 collabs.

The average is (3 + 2 + 3 + 2) / 4 = 2.5

How can I write query statement to achieve?
I can write query use "join" to filt book after 2000, and get a table like following:

```
SELECT key, sub1.author
FROM (
    SELECT key, author FROM authorCollection
) sub1
JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM book
    WHERE year >= 2000
) sub2 USING (key)

key author

2  Tim
2  Tony
2  Mary
3  Tim
3  Tony
3  Alex
```

How can I achieve the following? Thanks.

Comment: You should share your current query so we know what stage your are. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Imagine if you include all years.... will `TOM` have 0 collaborators?

Comment: yes, tom has 0 collaborator.

Comment: Your edit will destroy the question, I had to revert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First join `authorCollection` with itself to find what partner have. I use left join because you see `TOM` doesnt have partners.

Then Count how many distinct partners each one have.

Finally average those totals.

```
WITH partners as  (
    SELECT b.year, a1.author author1, a2.author author2
    FROM authorCollection a1
    LEFT JOIN authorCollection a2
      ON a1.key = a2.key
     AND a1.author <> a2.author
    JOIN books b
      ON b.key = a1.key
     AND year >= 2000
), npartner as (
    SELECT author1, COUNT(DISTINCT author2) np
    FROM partners
    GROUP BY author1
)
SELECT AVG(np)
FROM npartner
```

**NOTE:**

This

```
SELECT key, sub1.author
FROM (
    SELECT key, author FROM authorCollection
) sub1
```

is equal to this, so no need make thing complicated

```
SELECT key, sub1.author
FROM authorCollection sub1
```